# Help finding specific isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}^{2g}$ and $K^2$.

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, vector-space-isomorphism, symplectic-linear-algebra

I'm reading McMullen's [paper](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Ectm/papers/home/text/papers/bild/bild.pdf) "Billiards and Teichmüller Curves on Hilbert Modular Surfaces." I am stuck on understanding isomorphism (6.2) in the "Hilbert modular varieties" subsection of section 6 on page 18.

Here is the set-up:
Let $K = \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ be a totally real number field over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $g$, where $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension. Consider the lattice $L_0 = \mathbb{Z}^{2g}$ with the standard symplectic form $E_0$ satisfying $E_0(a_i, b_j) = \delta_{ij}$. Suppose we have an embedding $K \to \text{End}(L_0) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ sending the generator $\alpha$ to an endomorphism $T$ that satisfies $E_0(Tx, y) = E_0(x, Ty)$.

McMullen says that because $T$ is self-adjoint (in the above sense), we can find a $K$-linear isomorphism
$$ L_0 \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong K^2 $$
that sends $E_0$ to the "standard symplectic form" $E_1$ on $K^2$
$$
E_1(k, \ell) = \text{Tr}_\mathbb{Q}^K \det \begin{pmatrix} k_1 & k_2 \\ \ell_1 & \ell_2\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The trace here is the [field trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_trace), i.e., the sum over the Galois conjugates.

Does anyone see how to use the correspondence between $\alpha$ and $T$ to build the isomorphism carrying one symplectic form to the other? Moreover, does anyone have a reference discussing this symplectic form on $K^2$?

Comment: Hi there. I notices that you used one rare existing tags and three new tags. I don't have the expertise to judge if those tags are necessary, but tagging like this means that your post cannot be effectively searched. How about adding some more popular tags?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Your question reminds me of comparing two proofs of Theorem 2.1(b) in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/matrixconj.pdf.  For a number field $K = \mathbf Q(\alpha)$ of degree $n$ over $\mathbf Q$, the proof on pages 3-5 treats $\mathbf Q^n$ as a (one-dimensional) $K$-vector space. The second, more abstract, proof in Remark 2.6 on page 5 views the field $\mathbf Q(\alpha)$ as $\mathbf Q \otimes_\mathbf Z \mathbf Z[\alpha]$, and I am reminded of that when you write $L_0 \otimes \mathbf Q \cong K^2$ for $L_0 = \mathbf Z^{2g}$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference!